# Can repeated columns be combined in an Oracle result set that uses Group By clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to write a query in Oracle 11g that joins the following two tables, computes an average of the VAL1 column (based on the GROUP BY clause) and also returns a value for the VAL2 column, if present.

The query I came up with, however, contains duplicate rows for the same JOB_ID if there is a value present in VAL2.

Here are the tables:

```
 Table: JOB_BUDGET

  JOB_ID   VAL1    VAL2      JB_DATE
------------------------------------------------ 
   1        11       12      8/8/2016   <--val2 is always the same
   1        12       12      8/8/2016   <--val2 is always the same
   1        10       12      8/8/2016   <--val2 is always the same
   3         1       NULL    8/8/2016
   4        .5       NULL    8/8/2016
   5         3       NULL    8/8/2016


 Table: JOB_GROUP

 GROUP_ID   GROUP_NAME   JOB_ID
----------------------------------- 
   10006         A1          1
   10006         A1          2           
   10007          B          3
   10005          C          4
   10004          D          5
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT                            
   JG.JG_ID, 
   JG.JG_NAME,   
   round(avg(JB.VAL1), 2),    
   JB.VAL2

FROM 
   JOB_GROUP JG, 
   JOB_BUDGET JB

WHERE                
   JB.job_date = to_date('20160808', 'yyyyMMdd')  AND
   JB.job_id   = JG.job_id                               

 GROUP BY 
   jg.jg_id,
   jg.jg_name, 
   jb.val2
```

Here are the results I'm getting:

```
JG_ID   JG_NAME  VAL1_AVG   VAL2
 10004     D        3        NULL
 10006    A1       11        NULL
 10006    A1       11         12
 etc...
```

In the second and third row of the results, VAL1_AVG is duplicated.

Can the query be changed to combine those two rows into one row?

This is what I would like to see (multiple rows for a single jg_id/jg_name combo have been combined in one row):

```
JG_ID   JG_NAME  VAL1_AVG   VAL2
 10004     D        3        NULL
 10006    A1       11         12   
 etc...
```

Comment: Which `VAL2` would a combined row have?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - it would only have non-null values.

Comment: And it only has one non-null value? If so wouldn't getting `max(val2)` be enough, instead of grouping by `val2`?

Comment: There could be hundreds of rows with a VAL1 but no VAL2, for the same job_id and date. That's why I have the avg() function.

Comment: OK, but for a given 'job_id', will there only ever be a single non-null `val2`; and for a given job group will there only ever be a single `job_id` that has a non-null `val2`? My point is, in your current grouped output can will you always only have a single  non-null`val2` for each `jg_id`/`jg_name` combination? If not then you need to decide which one you show; and possibly which one the `val1` values linked to the null `val2` are averaged with. Maybe you can show more data/scenarios and expected results, as I don't think it's clear what you need at the moment.

Comment: Yes, in my current grouped output, I will always have a single non-null val2 for each jg_id/jg_name combination.   I edited the example data above, and added my desired results.  In an effort to simplify what is actually a much larger query (with other joins, etc), I made it too simple.

Comment: By the way, 'VAL2' represents a user-entered overridden value to val1, that is the same for ALL val1s with the same jg_id/jg_name combo.

Comment: With your query modified a bit so it works, now you get a single row for 10006. If `val2` was the same for all `job_id`/`val1` combinations - which isn't what you've said - and you had a job with ID 2 (so in the same group) and null `val2`, you could get your example output again; but then you either just need `max(val2)`, or you still have the potential for that second job to have a different `val2`.